# MUI Tabs implementation doesn't allow component wrappers around tabs

Tags: material-ui, tabs

As said, when I wrap a "Tab" component in a simple react function it no longer works. I'm new to React and MUI so perhaps there is something obvious I'm missing.

The effect is that it does render the tabs, but when you click the tab it doesn't call the TabList onChange handler nor does it seem to acknowledge the current tab "value" state.

The below is slightly modified from the examples provided on the Tabs demo page. Note that everything is pretty much the same except that it wraps "Tab" with "FTab":

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";
import TabContext from "@mui/lab/TabContext";
import TabList from "@mui/lab/TabList";
import TabPanel from "@mui/lab/TabPanel";

export default function LabTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("1");

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const FTab = ({ num }) => {
    return <Tab label={"Item " + num} value={num} />;
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", typography: "body1" }}>
      <TabContext value={value}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
          <TabList onChange={handleChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example">
            <FTab num="1" />
            <FTab num="2" />
            <FTab num="3" />
          </TabList>
        </Box>
        <TabPanel value="1">Item One</TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value="2">Item Two</TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value="3">Item Three</TabPanel>
      </TabContext>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I'd like to useSelector in the FTab wrapper to track tab name changes.

My actual code is more complex but I've reduced it down to this example. I can put an onChange handler in the Tab component under FTab but then it doesn't change the appearance of the Tab header when its selected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use *Integers* instead of *Strings* for the tab value.
2. Rename the *num* prop to *value* in FTab
3. Forward props in *FTab* to the Tab component.
4. Additionally you may need to set the muiName static property to *Tab.muiName*

```
const FTab = ({ value, ...props }) => {
  return <Tab label={"Item " + value} value={value} {...props} />
};

FTab.muiName = Tab.muiName
```

See Mui docs on Wrapped Components:
https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/composition/#wrapping-components